# xcode attributes inspector text value not shown properly (too long text)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Xcode attributes inspector seems to not show all text descriptions.  Because there are too many `textfield` (Xcode version: 9).

heres the screenshot:

[image]

I tried to resize the window, but it seems that the `textfield` cannot be resized, and do not show the text attributes.

How can I show all the text attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Hover over on inspector text value it will show full text in popup.

[image]

[image]

Hope it will help you.